# Is it possible to fetch / query the pressed keys on keyboard without events?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if events are required to get the currently pressed keys (or mouse buttons by extension) with Javascript.

Is there any way to fetch or query the keys without any events, and thus be able to get them with a simple loop (for example).

Comment: Any reason for not using events?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Well. That is not the question here but I will answer you: I want to be able to fetch key pressed along with other inputs and I don't want to write dozens of events with the same code block inside.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran I do not want to fire events by pressing keys. I want to know what keys are pressed from somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The act of pressing a key fires an event, regardless of whether or not you have an event handler for that event configured.

As to whether or not you need an event handler to detect a key press - I believe the answer is yes you do.

However, you could simulate the functionality you are requesting with a global object variable, and an event handler each for `keydown` and `keyup` which stores the pressed key and removes the released key in the aforementioned variable. Your loop can then just take a look at the global variable.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought so. I hoped there was (in-browser) an internal object storing an array of pressed keys.